# What is the link between ssl ciphers I use (string length, strength of ciphers) and nginx performance?

Tags: nginx

All is in the question.

I am wondering whether how using each ciphers or another would impact performance. Is there a huge impact ?

Is the impact linked to the type of content deserved ? (static or dynamic)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the key is really a reflection of the protocol used. The actual length of the secret provided is padded to a fixed length so generally, no the secret key length does not impact performance UNLESS it crosses over to a different protocol such as going from a 128 bit cypher to 256 bit.

At that point yes there is more CPU and other overhead that translates to performance... to work with keys of twice the size.

Comment: Are you talking about the key file for the ssl certificate ? By "string length" I meant "ciphersuit length". I don't really understand your answer

Comment: The PKI has nothing to do with it. The question was about the cipher string length and algorithm. These are associated. As to whether dynamic or static content... there is no difference as all content on the wire from host to client is encrypted via SSL. Some algorithms are faster than others but not relative to the content length. Twice as much content generally takes twice as long. A 128 bit cipher would be faster but not as strong as 256 bit.

Comment: I don't understand the "crossing" part to another protocol. When server receives client cipher suits list and then choose one to use, why would there be a change in the protocol ?

Comment: The question was "What is the link between ssl ciphers I use (string length, strength of ciphers) and nginx performance?". The link is that the actual key size/length is related to the protocol. 128 bit ciphers use smaller keys than 256 bit ciphers. If the user selects AES256, the key length will be shorter than AES512. The relationship thereafter about performance is that indeed, larger key ciphers run slower than smaller ones but closer to O(n) linear performance difference versus the strength of the larger key size, which is closer to O(log n) in time to brute-force.